# Can a LSL Script "touch" an object running a script

Tags: linden-scripting-language

Can a Linden LSL script running in an object TOUCH another object so as to trigger it, as if an avatar touched it?   I have a box that runs a script when it is touched by an avatar.  I want another box running a script to "touch" it for me and turn it on, and then off.

I looked through some LSL posts but did not see anything about this.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can trigger a touch event is with an SL client sending a touch command. So in other words, the only way you could do this is by setting up a bot agent to simulate a touch, which probably isn't practical.

You would be better off just using a listen and a chat command, if you can edit the script in the target object.